How to fix this issue with moving a rectangle?
I have been learning on how to develop and game in Java and I had come across this tutorial on how to develop but I got stuck on this keyboard input and timing of a rectangle on screen. I couldn't find why it wouldn't move. The code showed no signs for error or warnings, am I doing something wrong here? I don't know..so if anyone could help..it would be nice
package main;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(600,600);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("Pokemon");

        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        window.add(gamePanel);

        window.pack();

        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        gamePanel.startGameThread();
    }
}

This is my Gamepanel class
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    final int originalTitleSize = 16;
    final int scale = 3;

    final int tileSize = originalTitleSize * scale;
    final int maxScreenCol = 16;
    final int maxScreenRow = 12;
    final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol;
    final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow;

    int FPS = 60;

    KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler();
    Thread gameThread;

    int playerX = 100;
    int playerY = 100;
    int playerSpeed = 4;

    public GamePanel(){

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void startGameThread(){

        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {

        double drawInterval = (double) 1000000000/FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;

        while(gameThread != null) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();

            delta += (currentTime = lastTime) / drawInterval;

            lastTime = currentTime;

            if(delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(){
        if(keyH.upPressed){
            playerY -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.downPressed) {
            playerY += playerSpeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.leftPressed) {
            playerX -= playerSpeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.rightPressed) {
            playerX += playerSpeed;
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(playerX, playerY, tileSize, tileSize);

        g2.dispose();
    }
}

This is my KeyHandler class
package main;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener{

    public boolean upPressed, downPressed, leftPressed, rightPressed;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            upPressed = true;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            downPressed = true;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            leftPressed = true;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            rightPressed = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            upPressed = false;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
            downPressed = false;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            leftPressed = false;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            rightPressed = false;
        }
    }
}

First I checked the Tutorial again to see whether I missed anything or had done something wrong but I didn't find anything. Then i tried googling so see if that would work out but it didnt have much effect either

You are updating your GUI on a thread which is not the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). The fact that it [supposedly] works - as stated in the answer - is probably more by accident than by design. There are many questions on SO like yours and they all do the same as you, i.e. update the GUI on a thread which is not the EDT.

Don't use a KeyListener to handle KeyEvents. Instead you should be using Key Bindings. See: Motion Using the Keyboard for more information and working examples.

In your GamePanel class in the run() method there is this line:
delta += (currentTime = lastTime) / drawInterval;

I believe the (currentTime = lastTime) part should be (currentTime - lastTime) . So change the = character with - . I tested the code, it should work.
Edit 1: After reading @Abra's comment i think we should call the repaint() method in EDT. So use:
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::repaint);

instead of:
repaint();


I tried it right now but it still didn't work

Interesting. Because i tested on my machine and it works pretty well. What is the error you are getting? What exactly doesn't work?

Im not getting any errors but the rectangle just wont move

The rectangle on the screen wont move when i press the WASD

is it because of the IDE i use?

I dont think it's because of the IDE. Let's check some of the things. First i want you to put print lines on your ``KeyHandlerclass. See if it really captures the key events. And check if the pressed key and and your key values (example:KeyEvent.VK_S`) matches.

Ohk I did it but i dont know if this is how you do it:
public void update(){
if(keyH.upPressed){
System.out.println("Key is pressed");         }
else if (keyH.downPressed) {
System.out.println("Key is pressed");         }
else if (keyH.leftPressed) {
System.out.println("Key is pressed");         }
else if (keyH.rightPressed) {
System.out.println("Key is pressed");         }
}

So? did you see any of these lines printed?

no. None of them where printed in the terminal...

Well something is not right. Are you sure you are properly compiling and running your code. It seems your changes doesn't have any affect.

I'm running the code in an IDE. The build was successful, but I still can't get the rectangle to move.

Add a print statement on the first line of your code. That would be on the App.java main method. If that print statement doesn't get printed there is a problem how you compile your program.

Yeah it does print the statement

Then there might be a problem with the KeyHandler. As you said it doesn't catch your key events. Add line breaks in the methods of your KeyHandler class, check if they are working by debugging. Also add this line on the keyPressed method on your KeyHandler.
System.out.println("Pressed Key: " + e.getKeyCode() + " | Control Keys: " + KeyEvent.VK_W + " " + KeyEvent.VK_S + " " + KeyEvent.VK_A + " " + KeyEvent.VK_D);
Show me the output.

It doesn't print anything :(

I'm so confused right now. Your KeyHandler class doesn't work at all. But i don't know why. Your code seems perfectly fine to me and it works on my machine. Maybe It has something to do with this comment

It is not necessary to push the call to repaint() into EDT, repaint() is a way to push a call to paint on behalf the EDT.

Your code has some small problems, first, the main method, should be:
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> {
      JFrame fran = new JFrame();
      fran.setSize( 600, 600 );
      fran.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      fran.setResizable( false );
      fran.setTitle( "Pokemon" );
      GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
      fran.add( gamePanel );
      fran.pack();
      fran.setLocationRelativeTo( null );

        // it is essential that this is the last line of the “JFrame” instantiation
      fran.setVisible( true );
      gamePanel.startGameThread();
   } );
}

In this way, we ensure that the application is executed on the corresponding thread.
I have also made some modifications to your class GamePanel:
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

   final int originalTitleSize = 16;
   final int scale = 3;
   final int tileSize = originalTitleSize * scale;
   final int maxScreenCol = 16;
   final int maxScreenRow = 12;
   final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol;
   final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow;
   int FPS = 60;
   KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler();

     // change "Thread" for "Timer", "Timer" triggers events at regular intervals,
     // which is what is needed
   Timer gameThread;
   int playerX = 100;
   int playerY = 100;

     // changed for smoother movement ¿? 
   int playerSpeed = 1;

     // create an Image, this avoids drawing the same thing over and over again
   Image rect;

   public GamePanel() {
      setPreferredSize( new Dimension( screenWidth, screenHeight ) );
      setBackground( Color.black );
      setDoubleBuffered( true );
      addKeyListener( keyH );
      setFocusable( true ); 
      
      rect = new BufferedImage( 100, 100, 2 );
      Graphics2D gra = ( Graphics2D ) rect.getGraphics();
      gra.fillRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
   }

   public void startGameThread() { 

        // we instantiate the Timer, and start it
      gameThread = new Timer( 50, new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) { 
            update();
         }
      } );
      gameThread.start();
   }

   public void update() { 
      if( keyH.upPressed ) {
         playerY -= playerSpeed;
      }
      else if( keyH.downPressed ) {
         playerY += playerSpeed;
      }
      else if( keyH.leftPressed ) {
         playerX -= playerSpeed;
      }
      else if( keyH.rightPressed ) {
         playerX += playerSpeed;
      }
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      Graphics2D g2 = ( Graphics2D ) g;

        // here, we draw the image that we have preloaded
      g2.drawImage( rect, playerX, playerY, null ); 
   }

}

Surely this code can be improved, it is only one way among many.

Your answer is okay as it is, but explaining why you made these changes would improve your answer. Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the Concurrency in Swing section.

@GilbertLeBlanc, am a “low level” programmer, this low level (intimately linked to the time I have been programming), makes me not forget my first “misunderstandings” with the explanations of the particularities of Java, then (perhaps wrongly) I try to keep the explanation, within what I think the OP can understand, I do not think that if I talk about the event thread, he knows what I'm talking about, probably confuse him more (I have felt like that more than once), in some stages, it serves more the “do it this way” without deepening.

@GilbertLeBlanc, I still appreciate your comment, and I will try to adapt my response to your suggestion.

Well i checked more and found out that I had to add this line gamePanel.requestFocusInWindow();. It wasn't listed in the tutorial but was the problem.. Thank you to everyone for attending this question :)

Just goes to show how poor the quality of YouTube videos are. But the problem isn't just the videos, it's that people assume that they are good quality.
